# Stubbing method in same file using Sinon

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, reactjs, redux, sinon

I'm trying to unit test a function in a file while stubbing another function in the SAME file, but the mock is not being applied and the real method is being called.  Here's an example:

```
// file: 'foo.js'

export function a() {
   // .....
}

export function b() { 
   let stuff = a(); // call a
   // ...do stuff
}
```

And my test:

```
import * as actions from 'foo';

const aStub = sinon.stub(actions, 'a').returns('mocked return');
actions.b(); // b() is executed, which calls a() instead of the expected aStub()
```

Comment: As a general rule of thumb, you should not be stubbing/mocking a function in the same module you are testing. If you find that you need to do this, it is a good indication that the two functions should actually be in different modules. Of course, though, rules are made to be broken and there are situations where this might be OK, but in general, you should avoid.

Comment: @AndrewEisenberg I'm currently in this situation, and see that it is stil bit difficult to mock a function in the same module I'm testing. Can you elaborate on why, as a general rule of thumb, I should split the two functions into separate modules?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Some restructuring can make this work.

I've used commonJS syntax. Should work in the same way in ES6 as well.

foo.js

```
const factory = {
  a,
  b,
}
function a() {
  return 2;
}

function b() {
  return factory.a();
}

module.exports = factory;
```

test.js

```
const ser = require('./foo');
const sinon = require('sinon');

const aStub = sinon.stub(ser, 'a').returns('mocked return');
console.log(ser.b());
console.log(aStub.callCount);
```

Output

> mocked return
>
> 1

Comment: can you please provide example when functions a and b are receiving some argument and using es6 export syntax

Comment: Any explanation?

Comment: why does this work ?

Comment: @gaurav5430 what do you mean? Do you find any problem?

Comment: no i mean why does this restructuring work but the original code doesn't

Comment: @gaurav5430 `export function b() { 
   let stuff = a(); // call a
   // ...do stuff
}`  it would work if it was used as `actions.a()` instead of `a()` . In the original question, the import is a named import from the other module.

Answer (score 2):

While the above does work, it's definitely a workaround as my linter was quick to inform.

I ended up separating modules and using [proxyquire](https://github.com/thlorenz/proxyquire). This library allows you to easily substitute any / all exports with those of your choosing, sinon stub spy or mocks included. e.g. :

in b.js

```
export const fnB = () => 'hey there!';
```

in a.js

```
import { fbB } from 'b.js';
export const fnA = () => fbB();
```

in a.test.js

```
import { noCallThru } from 'proxyquire';
const proxyquireStrict = noCallThru();
const stubB = stub().returns('forced result');
const moduleA = proxyquireStrict('a.js', {
    'b.js' : { fnB: stubB }
}).fnA; 

console.log(fnA()); // 'forced result'
```

Comment: Isn't this also a workaround? 
What if it's not right to separate modules?

Answer (score 2):

The method mentioned above (using a `factory` to collect the functions) works well; however, eslint will not like the use of a variable/function that has not yet been declared. Therefore I would recommend a slight modification:

```
// my-functions.js
export const factory = {};
export const funcA = () => {
  return facory.funcB();
};
factory.funcA = funcA;
export const funcB = () => true;
factory.funcB = funcB;

// my-functions-test.js
import {factory, funcA, funcB} from './path/to/my-functions';

describe('MyFunctions | funcA', () => {
  test('returns result from funcB call', () => {
    const funcBStub = sinon.stub(factory, 'funcB').returns(false);

    // Test that the function does not throw errors
    let result;
    expect(() => (result = funcA())).not.toThrow();

    // Test that the return value is that of the mock rather than the original function
    expect(result).toEqual(false);

    // Test that the stub was called
    expect(funcBStub.called).toEqual(true);
  });
});

// Don't forget to test funcB independently ;)
```

The important distinction is to add the functions within the file to the `factory` as they are defined to avoid break eslint rules. The only case where this could cause issues is if you tried calling one of those functions within the same file before they have all been defined. Example:

```
// my-functions-1.js
export const factory = {};

export const funcA = () => {
  factory.funcB();
};
factory.funcA = funcA;

// Since the code execution runs from top to bottom, calling funcA here means that funcB has not yet been added to factory
funcA(); // Throws an error since factory.funcB() is not a function (yet)

export const funcB = () => true;
factory.funcB = funcB;
```

I prefer this technique of using a "collector" to call functions within the same file since it is not always a great idea to create separate files for EACH function that you write. Often, I find that I will create many related utility functions in order to make my code more readable, reusable, and composable; putting each function into a separate file would make the code slightly more difficult to understand since a reader could not see the definitions of these functions without bouncing between different files.

Answer (score 1):

I met with the same issue and found one method. You can change your foo.js file to this:

```
// file: 'foo.js'

export function a() {
   // .....
}

export function b() { 
   let stuff = exports.a(); // using "exports." to call a
   // ...do stuff
}
```

Please refer to https://codeburst.io/stub-dependencies-with-sinon-js-259ac12379b9.