# How to mock s3.upload() with Jest - node.js

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, jestjs

I try to mock s3 upload function with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60970919/using-jest-fn-to-see-if-s3-upload-function-was-called-what-am-i-doing-wrong/62753449#62753449) instruction but when I use this pattern a have an

> TypeError: s3.upload is not a function

```
// upload.test.js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
  const mS3 = { upload: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(), promise: jest.fn() };
  return { S3: jest.fn(() => mS3) };
});

const s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3.upload({}).promise.mockResolvedValueOnce({ Bucket: 'XXX' });
```

I'm using also SQS and with this pattern I have another error:

> AWS.SQS is not a constructor

How I can handle with it?

```
// upload.js
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
s3Params = {
        Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
        Key: `example.xml`,
        ACL: 'public-read',
        ContentType: 'application/json',
        Body: Buffer.from(file)
      }
    }
await s3.upload(s3Params).promise();
```

Comment: [sinon](https://sinonjs.org/)

Answer (score 1):

when using Jest `.mockReturnValueOnce`, you need to execute the mock AFTER that value is set to be able to receive the value you defined in `mockReturnValueOnce` as a response,

for example, mocking S3:

```js
// s3-mock.test.js
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');

jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
  let instance = {
    upload: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    promise: jest.fn(),
  };
  return { S3: jest.fn(() => instance) };
});


describe("setup for s3.upload testing", () => {
  let testS3;
  beforeEach(() => {
    testS3 = new AWS.S3();
    testS3.promise.mockReturnValueOnce({ Bucket: 'TestBucketName' });
  })

  test('returns expected upload value', async () => {
    let params = {};
    let result = await testS3.upload(params).promise();
    expect(result).toEqual({ Bucket: 'TestBucketName' });
    expect(result.Bucket).toBe("TestBucketName")
  });
});
```

and mocking SQS:

```js
// sqs-mock.test
let AWS = require('aws-sdk');

jest.mock('aws-sdk', () => {
  let instance = {
    sendMessage: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    promise: jest.fn(),
  };
  return { SQS: jest.fn(() => instance) };
});


describe("setup for sqs.sendMessage testing", () => {
  let testSQS;
  beforeEach(() => {
    testSQS = new AWS.SQS();
    testSQS.promise.mockReturnValueOnce({ MessageId: 'TestSQSId' });
  })

  test('returns expected message id', async () => {
    let params = {};
    let result = await testSQS.sendMessage(params).promise();
    expect(result).toEqual({ MessageId: 'TestSQSId' });
    expect(result.MessageId).toBe("TestSQSId")
  });
});
```

working example on https://github.com/oieduardorabelo/jest-mock-aws-sdk

as you can see, they are identical, you can also use manual mocks in Jest with a folder `__mocks__` with all packages you and to mock in your tests, have a look at the docs on: https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks

Answer (score -1):

Instead of `aws-sdk` try using `aws-sdk/clients/s3`.